# why it is necessary to import CommonModule to other custom/child modules when it is being imported and re-exported in the root module (AppModulle)

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-module

Assume I have an app that has two modules

- `AppModule`
- `MyChildModule`

`CommonModule` is imported and re-exported by `AppModule`

`MyChildModule` is imported to `AppModule`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        MyChildModule
    ],
    exports:[
        CommonModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

`CommonModule` is **NOT IMPORTED** to `MyChildModule`

**childModule.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      MyChildComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
    ],
    exports:[
        MyChildComponent,
    ]
})
```

**my-child-module-component.ts**

```
export class ChildModuleComponent{
      showMessage:boolean;
      constructor(){
         this.showMessage = true;
      }
}
```

**Child-module-component.html**

```
<h1 *ngIf ='showMessage'> Hello World </h1>
```

now the issue is when I add `childComponent` to `appComponent` it says `*ngIf` is not a know property. since `*ngIf` is a directive of `commonModule` and both `childModule` and `commonModule` are imported to the same module which is `AppModule`

**app.component.ts**

```
<my-child-component></my-child-component> <!-- *it should display *Hello World text* -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to export it in AppModule

1. Nothing is "importing App Module" in your example, and in general.
2. You can always import that module elsewhere, so no need to export here.

You need to import CommonModule inside your ChildModule,
From the doc https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule , you need it for *ngIf pipe for example.

Think of the childModule as an independent container, where to start it has to have everything needed ( in this case, it's ask for *ngIf, ie. CommonModule )

IMPORTANT: Once declared in a module, a component can't be imported inside another module

What you want to do in your example :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      MyChildComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    exports:[
        MyChildComponent,
    ]
})
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: why `CommonModule` is not accessible by `MyChildModule` since both are part of `AppModule`? I assumed that if the parent Module (`AppModule`) has `CommonModule` then `CommonModule`  should be accessible by all other modules that are imported to the `AppModule`. especially that the `CommonModule` is exported (made it public just like `MyChildComponent` is public to appComponent and appComponent is not part of childModule.

Comment: The relationship goes only one way. 
`AppModule --- imports --> ChildModule`, 
`AppModule --- imports --> CommonModule`

AppModule can have access to anything exported by `ChildModule, CommonModule`

ChildModule can't have access to what AppModule exports here ( as it's not importing AppModule... but this wouldn't make any sense to import AppModule here.  A -> B , B -> A )

I am not sure if that answer more your question.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules I'd advise you to have another look on how Module works with angular